# Hide query string in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to hide the query string from url when the page reloads.

I have a link on my home page view which changes the language of the site the link looks like this

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/box/<?php echo $template_data['box_id'] ?>/<?php echo $lang['language_name'] ?>/?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>&lid=<?php echo $lang['language_id'] ?>">
```

I want to hide the id and lid from my url when the page reloads 
I cant use session and cookies because my coding is done in such a way that its not possible to use them

Any other possibility ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I know you said you can't use sessions and cookies, but if it's just so that you're not storing data that you don't want the user to see, maybe CI's flashdata method would be of help as it is only stored for one page view: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's not possible - the browser needs to have the URL to send a request to a page, and that's exactly what it will display to the user. At *very best*, you could hack in a little history-changing JavaScript with `pushState`, but that's a terrible solution. You'll need some other way. One way to do it would be through POST, depending on your reason for having it:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/box/<?php echo $template_data['box_id'] ?>/<?php echo $lang['language_name'] ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lid" value="<?php echo $lang['language_id'] ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Style this like a link" />
</form>
```

Not elegant, but it's the only way to do that in a compatible fashion. If this still isn't feasible, you may need to rethink your pattern and why you need to hide this information.

Comment: The other worst thing is that I dont want to change my link to form :)

Comment: @FaryalKhan: Impossible! So, what's the issue? Why does this need to be done? Perhaps there's a better way.

Comment: @FaryalKhan: Tell him it's not possible then. But is there *any good reasoning at all* behind this? A security concern?

Comment: yes some security concern I already told him u can hide the paths from a normal users but not from programmer :) I hope i will convince him

Comment: tell him to quit focusing on the micro-shit, and to focus on encryption and code integrity.. also tell him to change his password from `password` on his pc. Oh and tell him to quit micro-managing you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect again to remove query part. Or rewrite url by routing and make it look like **`http://example.com/home/box/<temp>/<lang>/<id>/<lang_id>`**

and from controller catch varibles with `$this->uri->segment(n)`

But i dont see point to hide the query

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use some kind of 2-way encoding?
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html

This way you don't have to change the uri and you just have to decode the values before processing (and encode before sending). Off course, anyone who knows you are using CI still has access to the real values so a custom encryption method would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Why to hide the url or parts of it? Let's see an example:
http://www.sturm.xxx:8080/client/index.php/c_registration/modify_my_account/12

After log in, the user can modify his registration data (password, email address, etc.).
In the link above the number 12 is the user id. If the user clever enough, rewrites the user id, and voila, can steal or modify another user's personal data.